# How to set -- Comments inside the variable declare?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

```
SELECT * FROM CUSTOMERS 
--WHERE ID='1'
```

I want the result like above statement, anyone can advice this can be declare comments or any other way?

```
DECLARE @TEST as VARCHAR(2) ='--'

SELECT * FROM CUSTOMERS 
@TEST WHERE ID='1'
```

Comment: It is not possible. Perhaps you can explain what is the objective of doing this ?

Comment: My objective is I have many where condition is using -- comments, so I want know have any fast way to disable -- comments, then after enable back the -- comments?

Comment: No you cannot write code to comment out code :)

Comment: Parameters are always processed as *values*. The sql command is never expanded to include the value of the parameters - that's why parameters can protect you against (sql-) injection attacks.

Comment: I think what you want is to conditionally run parts of the query, not conditionally add comments. Is that correct?

Comment: yes, I want to swap each other conditionally

Answer (score 3):

There is no preprocessor that can do what you want, and if there would be a preprocessor, it would probably only work in specific client software (like SQL Server Management Studio).

The best I can come up with is declaring a `BIT` variable and include it in your `WHERE` statement's logic.

```
DECLARE @TEST BIT = 0;  -- Change to 1 for testing (which will show all records instead of only the record with ID = '1')

SELECT * FROM CUSTOMERS 
WHERE ID = '1' OR @TEST = 1;
```

But using `OR`s in a `WHERE`-clause can become a performance issue (due to not using indexes), so using a `UNION` might be a solution in that case:

```
DECLARE @TEST BIT = 0;  -- Change to 1 for testing (which will show all records instead of only the record with ID = '1')

SELECT * FROM CUSTOMERS
WHERE ID = '1'
UNION
SELECT * FROM CUSTOMERS 
WHERE @TEST = 1;
```

I would personally go for the first option and fall back to the second option if that would produce a better query execution plan.

The latter solution does have the drawback that you have to duplicate your query logic, so changes have to be made in two places instead of one.

It's also the question if you would like to include such a testing variable at all. You can include a complete test query in comments:

```
/*
-- For testing purposes:
SELECT * FROM CUSTOMERS
*/

SELECT * FROM CUSTOMERS 
WHERE ID = '1';
```

In SSMS, you can simply select the text *inside* the comment block and hit F5. Only the selected statement(s) will be parsed and executed.

Finally, if you have a large script with many testing cases, you could consider using a separate test script for that. In case of changes, you would have to maintain two scripts, of course, but everything related to testing is cleanly separated that way.

Comment: Aside: [`Boolean`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/comparison-operators-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017#boolean-data-type) != [`Bit`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/bit-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017).

Answer (score 2):

Try following statement:

```
DECLARE @TEST BIT = 1
DECLARE @ID NVARCHAR(50) = N'1'

SELECT *
CUSTOMERS as c
WHERE @TEST = 1 OR c.ID = @ID
```

So you can test without commenting out...

Another option is dynamic statements:

```
DECLARE @Statement NVARCHAR(4000) = NULL
DECLARE @TEST BIT = 1

IF @TEST = 1
BEGIN
     SET @Statement = N'SELECT * FROM CUSTOMERS AS c'
END
ELSE
BEGIN
     SET @Statement = N'SELECT * FROM CUSTOMERS AS c WHERE c.ID = @ID'
END

EXEC sp_executesql @Statement,
N'@ID NVARCHAR(50)',
@ID = N'1'
```

Comment: How to write the statement for two declare variable? After EXEC sp_executesql @Statement, this part

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-executesql-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

...N'@ID NVARCHAR(254), @TEST BIT' ...

You can also set this declared parameters in an own variable (see link)

Answer (score 1):

By Using **Dynamic SQL Query**.You can Set your Common SQL Command in One Variable and the based on your need/Requirement you can `CONCAT` the String and this can be achieved from by using Dynamic SQL

```
DECLARE @TEST VARCHAR(MAX),@Where VARCHAR(MAX)=' WHERE ID=''1'''

IF(Condition Check)
SET @TEST='SELECT * FROM CUSTOMERS' +@Where
ELSE
SET @TEST='SELECT * FROM CUSTOMERS'

SELECT @TEST

EXEC (@TEST)
```

Another Option:

```
DECLARE @TEST VARCHAR(2) =NULL

SET @TEST='1'

SELECT * FROM CUSTOMERS 
WHERE (ID=@TEST OR @TEST IS NULL)
```

Comment: Your other option is the way how I normally handle optional parameters in parameterized queries. :) But note that using `OR`s in a `WHERE` clause can degrade performance. It seems that the query optimizer often cannot make use of indexes in such cases.

Answer (score 0):

For quick debugging I'm using pattern like next:

```
declare @var int   -- can be some function or procedure param

select f1, f2, ... -- can be update or delete too
--declare @var int = 7; select *
from mytable
where id = @var
```